# XML Serialization and a Class with Binary Property - How can I get this to work?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following serialization method shown below. The problem is that I am attempting to pass a class to it that contains a property of type Binary. The serialization is failing because of this property type. Is there any way I can serialize a class with a property of type Binary?

```
    private string Serialize<TEntity>(TEntity instance)
    {
        string retStr = "";
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TEntity));
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        xs.Serialize(writer, instance);
        retStr = writer.ToString();
        writer.Close();

        return retStr;
    }
```

Here is the portion of the class that represents the Binary property.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Row version number
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public System.Data.Linq.Binary VersionNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: "`Binary`" is not a .NET data type. How is it defined? Also, please post the exact exception you receive. Catch the exception, then post ex.ToString().

Comment: Can you show us snippet of the code where this property is defined?

Comment: Are you interested in a workaround or just making your way work?  Are you able to change the class you are having trouble serializing?  If you don't really care about the property, you could try [XmlIgnore]?

Comment: @Vivek - I've edited the question to show the property definition.

Comment: @John- I've edited the question to show the property definition.

Comment: @Autolykos - I am able to change the class. But whatever I do, it must be able to be serialized for WCF.

Comment: Do you need to use the XML Serializer? Why not use the Data Contract Serializer (which also produces XML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just convert the `System.Linq.Binary` to byte[]? Internally both are same, except `System.Linq.Binary` is immutable. Also Binary class doesn't have a default constructor hence the serialization fails.

Further reading:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160529035554/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/frankw/archive/2008/08/29/serialization-issue-with-timestamp-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Bit late, but if someone else is looking for a solution, I will post mine here:

First, add System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore to the Binary Property:

in my Case:

```
 <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_Bericht", DbType:="VarBinary(MAX)", UpdateCheck:=UpdateCheck.Never),
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore> _
    Public Property Bericht() As System.Data.Linq.Binary
        Get
            Return Me._Bericht.Value
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Data.Linq.Binary)
            If (Object.Equals(Me._Bericht.Value, Value) = False) Then
                Me.OnBerichtChanging(Value)
                Me.SendPropertyChanging()
                Me._Bericht.Value = Value
                Me.SendPropertyChanged("Bericht")
                Me.OnBerichtChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

Second, add a new Property which will make the Binary value available as byte()

```
Public Property BerichtAsByte As Byte()
        Get
            If Me.Bericht Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
            Return Me.Bericht.ToArray
        End Get
        Set(value As Byte())
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Me.Bericht = Nothing
            Else
                Me.Bericht = New Data.Linq.Binary(value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

And that's it. Now the entity is serializable and stores all properties.

Answer (score 0):

While not a total solution to your problem, please try the following code:

```
private string Serialize<TEntity>(TEntity instance)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TEntity));
        using (System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, instance);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: @John - I don't mean to be ignorant but what is this code supposed to accomplish? It's basically what I'm doing now.

Comment: @Randy: it's what you were doing incorrectly, and if you get an exception, it grabs it for you to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert on WCF nor serialization, and the solution below is hacky at best and has only undergone brief verification.

```
public class HasBinaryProperty
{
    public byte[] versionBytes;

    public HasBinaryProperty()
    {//ignore this used it to test the serialization of the class briefly
        Random rand = new Random();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
        rand.NextBytes(bytes);
        this.VersionNumber = new Binary(bytes);
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Binary VersionNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return new Binary(this.versionBytes);
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionBytes = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```